# MoveIt tutorial: .yaml sensor file

Tags: ros, moveit, sensor, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to run the QuickStart tutorial for MoveIt! and I'm not being able to see any of the measurements from the sensors in Gazebo in the RViz.
I was wondering if anyone can tell me how the .yaml file sensors_rgbd.yaml works to get the sensor data from Gazebo to MoveIt! I've already checked and the /head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points topic is being published correctly from Gazebo, but there are no subscribers for it.

Thank you in advance,
Tiago

--------- Edit ------------------

So, I think I figured out a part of this. What I think is that I'm getting caught in this part of the code:

```
if (!sensor_list[i].hasMember ("sensor_plugin"))
{
    ROS_ERROR("No sensor plugin specified for octomap updater %d; ignoring.", i);
    continue;
}
```

Because in sensors_rgbd.yaml there is no sensor_plugin field. So, does anyone have an idea of what value should I give to it?

Thanks again,
Tiago Pimentel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63097/moveit-tutorial:-.yaml-sensor-file/) by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer to this problem already.

In the sensors_rgbd.yaml file, there's one important item missing that allows the sensor data to be transformed by move_group to be used in RViz.
You have to add the line:

```
sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
```

inside the sensor information, I put it right after:

```
point_cloud_topic: /head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points
```

so far as I understood, this tells move_group which plugin it should use to transform/understand the data from the sensor.

I hope this helps anyone that has the same problem I had!

Have a great day,
Tiago Pimentel

---

Originally posted by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) with karma: 385 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2